# Need help displaying a calculation at the end of this document

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to display the "totaldue" within the textbox at the bottom id'd as "output". I am currently not understanding how to display the totaldue within the textbox, so any help would be appreciated! Also I am wondering if I need any functions within the script tags... Under the assignment rubric it states that I should only be declaring variables within the script tags. Thanks guys!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title> Pizza Party</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <H1> PIZZA PLACE </H1>
        <!--Image goes here-->
        <center><img src="pizza.png" alt="Pizza" width="220px" height="160px"></center>
        <br><br>



        <script>
        function pricecalculate()
        {
         var cheeseprice = 11.99*Number(cheese_value);
         var mushroomprice = 12.99*Number(mushroom_value);
         var sausageprice =13.49*Number(sausage_value);
         var veggieprice =12.49*Number(veggie_value);
         var deliver ="no";
         var tip = 0;
         var deliveryFee =0;
         var priceofpizza = cheeseprice + mushroomprice + sausageprice + veggieprice

         if (deliver="yes"){
            deliveryFee =3.99;
            }

        output.value = totaldue
         }


        </script>
        <p>Please designate the pizza type and the quantity in the boxes below</p>
        <p>Cheese <input type ="text" id="cheese" onchange=''></p>
        <p>Mushroom <input type ="text" id="mushroom" onchange=''></p>
        <p>Sausage <input type ="text" id="sausage" onchange=''></p>
        <p>Veggie <input type ="text" id="veggie" onchange=''></p>
        <br><br>

        <p>Delivery Preference</p>
        <p><input type ="radio" name="takeout" id="takeout" onlick=''>Takeout</p>
        <p><input type ="radio" name="delivery" id="delivery" onlick='deliver="yes"'>Delivery</p>

        <br><br>
        <p>Tip amount</p>
        <p><input type ="radio" name="fifteen" id="fifteen" onlick='var tip=0.15'>15%</p>
        <p><input type ="radio" name="eighteen" id="eighteen" onlick='var tip=0.18'>18%</p>
        <p><input type ="radio" name="twenty" id="twenty" onlick='var tip=0.20'>20%</p>
        <p><input type ="radio" name="notip" id="notip" onlick='var tip=0'>No Tip</p><!--All of the input boxes and directions to the user go below -->



        <!--this is the start of the button info -->
      <button id="totalSales" onclick = "
                     var totaldue = priceofpizza + (priceofpizza*tip) + deliveryFee
                     " >Calculate Total</button> <br>


        <input type="text" id="output">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of changes that needed to be made:

- The radio groups were being used incorrectly; radio buttons that belong to the same group need the same name or else multiple radios can be selected for one group
- You need to define a global variable to pass values between different scopes the way you were doing (for example `priceofpizza` doesn't exits in the scope of `onclick`  you used on your `<button>` element), I went ahead and handled this by declaring a `global`/`window` variable called `model`
- You need to actually retrieve the values of the input using the DOM (`document`)

```html
<html><head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Pizza Party</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1> PIZZA PLACE </h1>
        <!--Image goes here-->
        <center><img src="pizza.png" alt="Pizza" width="220px" height="160px"></center>
        <br><br>



        <script>
        window.model = {};
        window.pricecalculate = function()
        {
         model.cheeseprice = 11.99*Number(document.querySelector('#cheese').value);
         model.mushroomprice = 12.99*Number(document.querySelector('#mushroom').value);
         model.sausageprice =13.49*Number(document.querySelector('#sausage').value);
         model.veggieprice =12.49*Number(document.querySelector('#veggie').value);
         var deliveryOptions = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName('delivery-method')); // you need to use Array.prototype.slice.call to cast the NodeLits returned by document.getElementsByName into an Array and then use the Array's find method
         console.log(deliveryOptions);
         model.deliver =deliveryOptions.find(option => option.checked).value === 'delivery'
         var tipOptions = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName('tip'));
         model.tip = tipOptions.find(option => option.checked).value;

         model.deliveryFee =0;
         model.priceofpizza = model.cheeseprice + model.mushroomprice + model.sausageprice + model.veggieprice

         if (deliver="yes"){
            model.deliveryFee =3.99;
            }

         }


        </script>
        <p>Please designate the pizza type and the quantity in the boxes below</p>
        <p>Cheese <input type="text" id="cheese" onchange=""></p>
        <p>Mushroom <input type="text" id="mushroom" onchange=""></p>
        <p>Sausage <input type="text" id="sausage" onchange=""></p>
        <p>Veggie <input type="text" id="veggie" onchange=""></p>
        <br><br>

        <p>Delivery Preference</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="delivery-method" id="takeout" value="takeout">Takeout</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="delivery-method" id="delivery" value="delivery">Delivery</p>

        <br><br>
        <p>Tip amount</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tip" id="fifteen" value="0.15">15%</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tip" id="eighteen" value="0.18">18%</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tip" id="twenty" value="0.20">20%</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="tip" id="notip" value="0">No Tip</p><!--All of the input boxes and directions to the user go below -->



        <!--this is the start of the button info -->
      <button id="totalSales" onclick="
                     pricecalculate();
                     var totaldue = model.priceofpizza + (model.priceofpizza*model.tip) + model.deliveryFee
                     var output = document.querySelector('#output');
                     output.value = totaldue;
                     ">Calculate Total</button> <br>


        <input type="text" id="output">

</body></html>
```

Comment: I am still unable to receive an output in the box. Thank you though!

Comment: When I run that entire HTML in Chrome, its telling me `priceofpizza` doesn't exist. The script at the top defines a function that declares `priceofpizza`, that means `priceofpizza` only exists in the `pricecalculate` function, also that function is never called anywhere. I will update my answer shortly

Comment: thank you I appreciate it! totally new to html - thank you for valuable insight

Comment: The answer has been updated and I've listed out the major changes made. You should compare the answer with your original HTML, it will be a good learning experience if you are new to HTML/JS